# How to calculate the width of a CSS Grid column in IE11 for animation?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, css-grid

The 'Slide' button toggles a `left-margin`. Need to find a way to animate that `left-margin` however using a `transition` on any `calc`ed element seems to be bugged in IE11 - still.

Sample in JS Bin
https://jsbin.com/qirozodete/1/edit?html,css,output
and below.

This is a very simple mock up of the project I'm working on. Trying to create an element that slides & shrinks 1 `grid` column at every resolution. Currently using a `calc` to work out how big a grid column is, which works on FF/Chrome/Safari. Just not IE.

Don't think I can use `transform: translate` either as the element wouldn't shrink, and the `calcs` needed are a bit more complex than just stacking `translates`.

Any idea would be appreciated.

```js
document.getElementById('slide-btn').addEventListener('click', function() { 
  document.getElementById('grid').classList.toggle('slide'); 
})
```

```css
button {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

#grid {
  display: -ms-grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

#grid-item-1 {
  background: teal;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 2;
  height: 150px;
  transition: margin-left 500ms ease-in;
}

#grid.slide #grid-item-1 {
  margin-left: calc(100vw / 4);
}
```

```html
<button id="slide-btn">Slide</button>
<div id="grid">
    <div id="grid-item-1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"seems to be bugged in IE11 - still"_ — That "still" will be forever, it will never be fixed. IE11 is dead, it will only get security updates, no bugfixes, and even the security updates only while the last OS that it shipped with is supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and reproduced the issue. I think we can only use JavaScript to make changes as a workaround in IE. We can calculate the value of `clientWidth` and toogle the `marginLeft` value.

Sample code:

```js
document.getElementById('slide-btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var ml = document.getElementById("grid-item-1").style.marginLeft;
  var vw = (document.documentElement.clientWidth) / 4;
  if (ml == "") {
    document.getElementById("grid-item-1").style.marginLeft = vw + "px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("grid-item-1").style.marginLeft = "";
  }
})
```

```css
button {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

#grid {
  display: -ms-grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( 4, 1fr);
}

#grid-item-1 {
  background: teal;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-column-span: 2;
  grid-column: span 2;
  height: 150px;
  transition: margin-left 500ms ease-in;
}
```

```html
<button id="slide-btn">Slide</button>
<div id="grid">
  <div id="grid-item-1"></div>
</div>
```